# Error in creating GoogleTV AVD, with Android Developers Tools R14

Tags: android, ubuntu, kvm, google-tv

I have installed `KVM` , but when creating GoogleTV AVD on using Google Addon 3.1 . I get this error ..

```
Failed to parse properties from /home/adham/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/congfig.ini
```

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the config.ini yourself as a workaround, some example contents:

```
hw.lcd.density=213
hw.keyboard.charmap=Emulator
skin.name=720.p
skin.path=add-ons/addon-google_tv-google_inc_-12/skins/720p
hw.cpu.arch=x86
abi.type=x86
vm.heapSize=256
hw.ramSize=1024
disk.dataPartition.size=128
image.sysdir.2=platforms/android-12/images/
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon-google_tv-google_inc_-12/images/x86/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding bug with the r14 version of the Android Developer Tools. More information about the bug, plus a possible workaround, can be found on [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20963).

Comment: Then what ? no solution till now ?!

Comment: @adham: Monitor the issue and watch for word of a solution, if the workaround listed there did not work for you.

Comment: @comminsWare ,, sorry :( .. do you mean this comment ? "Workaround for the impatient like me: download r12 and manually copy the necessary files from r14, since Google addon mirrors for r12 have been disabled."  ,, I don't get the point !!